# Variable type annotations leading to warnings

Tags: python, annotations, pycharm, python-3.4

I'm new to Python development, and trying to get a fix on things. I am using Pycharm for development. I am currently trying to annotate the types of variables for easier access with autocompletion and suggestions. I've tried iterations of the code with mixed results.

This is the code that has a problem:

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))  # type: str
components = path.split(os.sep)  # type: list[str]
```

The first problem displayed is at the opening brace of the type annotation of the second line. It says:

```
Class 'type' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances.
```

I've googled around, and although the problem seems clear, opening the code for the `list` class clearly shows a method `__getitem__`:

```
class list(object):
    """
    list() -> new empty list
    list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
    """

....

    def __getitem__(self, y): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """ x.__getitem__(y) <==> x[y] """
        pass
```

Okay, maybe that's not trivial to understand and there's some other loading mechanism at work. And besides, the "problem" seems to be that I used `list[str]` and not `List[str]`. So I altered the code:

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))  # type: str
components = path.split(os.sep)  # type: List[str]
```

Now everything breaks: The second line now complains about this:

```
Expected type 'List[str]', got 'List[str]' instead`
```

The previous problem regarding `__getitem__` yet persists.

Is there a way to annotate these variables without causing problems for the checker? I am not very happy with the Python documentation in that regard, not explicitly stating the return types of their built-in methods. I have to rely on the information Pycharm provides in the documentation pop-ups (Ctrl+q).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a right solution to use `List[str]` instead of `list[str]` since builtin types could not be used in type hints, the corresponding [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) has not been accepted yet.

From what module do you import `List`? I'm unable to reproduce an issue in 2019.3.

Comment: Pycharm suggested `_ast.List(expr)`, and that's what I used.

Comment: Please switch to `typing.List`